# modify user-agent with decarativeNetRequest and refresh page with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

Am trying to migrate a toggle to manifest V3, this toggles between `web` and `mobile` view.
With new `declarativeNetRequest` am able to modify the header, but it does not reload page. Ideally after applying new mobile user agent, It supposed to reload and load page in mobile view.

I have declared dynamic rule in `declarativeNetRequest` as below:

```
const rules  = {
        addRules: [
          {
            id: 36,
            priority: 2,
            action: {
              type: 'modifyHeaders' as chrome.declarativeNetRequest.RuleActionType,
              requestHeaders: [
                {
                  header: 'user-agent',
                  operation: 'set' as chrome.declarativeNetRequest.HeaderOperation,
                  value: `mobileUserAgent`,
                },
              ],
            },
            condition: {
            urlFilter: 'example.com',
              resourceTypes: [
                'main_frame' as chrome.declarativeNetRequest.ResourceType,
                'xmlhttprequest' as chrome.declarativeNetRequest.ResourceType,
                ],
            },
          },
        ],
      }

     chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(rules, () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError)
        } else {
          chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules(rules => console.log(rules))
        }
      })
```

It does update the value when checking in chrome dev tool, but it does not refresh the page and does not load mobile view with new user agent.

FYI this is old way of doing this and it works fine, but it does not support in manifest V3
This is old way of modifying headers.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function (details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
        details.requestHeaders[i].value = details.requestHeaders[i].value + ' OurUAToken/1.0';
        break;
      }
    }
    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
  },
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
  ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);
```

what would be equivalent of `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener` in manifest V3?

Comment: Both approaches do not reload the page, they both modify the outgoing request. The difference is that the first code sets a limited resourceTypes. Try removing it. Also, devtools has bugs with showing DNR headers, so it's better to verify in an external tool like Fiddler, Charles, WireShark, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code, the tabs will use your mobile user agent. The tabs before running this code need to be reloaded with another code. Here's an example:

```
    chrome.windows.getCurrent({populate:true},function(window){ 
    for(var tab of window.tabs){
        for(var site of ["example.com"]){
            if(tab.url && tab.url.indexOf(site) >= 0)chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it completely like below.

Add **declarativeNetRequest** to your manifest.json file. And declare a *background.js* file too.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "your-app-name",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
      "declarativeNetRequest"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ], 
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
  }
```

Then in your background.js file paste the following JSON. Keep in mind to use your own needed **user-agent** in this JSON in the background.js file.

**Sample user-agent:**
*Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows CE; Mobile; like Android; ko-kr) AppleWebKit/533.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.3 Dorothy*

```
const rules = {
  removeRuleIds: [1],
  addRules: [
    {
      id: 1,
      priority: 1,
      action: {
        type: "modifyHeaders",
        requestHeaders: [
          {
            header: "user-agent",
            operation: "set",
            value: 'your-own-user-agent',
          },
        ],
      },
      condition: {
        resourceTypes: ["main_frame"],
        urlFilter: "*",
      },
    },
  ],
};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(rules);
});
```